# Recursively replace string in files

Tags: grep, sed

I want to replace the backslash in the string `page_path\example_filename.txt` with a forward slash.  I also want to be able to run this on a large file system and have it recursively search all directories.

I found someone on the web who said to use `grep`, `xargs`, and `sed` but I wasn't able to get it to work. I've been trying different variations on delimiters and escape characters, but didn't get it.

Here is the command I was trying to run:
`grep -lr -e 'page_path\\' * | xargs sed -i 's/page_path\/page_path//g'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) might interest you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can use find for that:

```
find /your/path -type f -exec grep -l 'page_path\\' {} \; -exec sed -i 's#page_path\\#page_path/#g' {} \;
```

The second exec will be executed only if the first one was succeed, and you won't get problems with unprintable or escape needing characters in file names.

Comment: Why are you using `grep` with `-l` here instead of `-q` ?

Comment: just to indicate list of files which were changed. but `-q` is also an option :)

Answer (score 6):

With `grep | xargs`, you get problems with whitespaces, quotes, backslashes (and possibly more depending on the `xargs` implementation) in filenames.

With the GNU implementations of `grep` and `xargs`, you can avoid those problems by using: `grep -lZr ... | xargs -r0  sed ...` which uses zero bytes as delimiter.

And now regarding the sed command: The trick is that you can use instead of `s/a/b/` any other character as a separator, e.g. `s#a#b#`:

```
sed -i 's#page_path\\#page_path/#g'
```

Comment: FYI, `grep` has a `-Z` option for null-delimited file names, so `grep -Z ... | xargs -0 ...` is the generally accepted way to do that.

Comment: cool, didn't know any character could work as a delimiter in sed

Answer (score 1):

Why waste CPU cycles on calling all those commands when **bash** has built functionality to do it with WAY less typing?

**Example**

```bash
str='page_path\example_filename.txt'
echo "${str//\\/\/}"
```

**Output**

```
page_path/example_filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`ripgrep` can help here as well, replace foo with what you what to match and then change both in `rg` invocation and in `sed` expression.

```bash
rg foo --files-with-matches | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

If your files may have whitespace in their names, tell ripgrep to separate them by NULL byte

```bash
rg foo --files-with-matches -0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

source: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/FAQ.md#search-and-replace